# Random characters show on real hardware but not simulator

Tags: string, hardware, x86-16, display, bootloader

I am writing my own boot-loader at the moment. I have been able to successfully load it on qemu and VirturalBox. I am however, having issues on real hardware.

Here is what it should look like (this is on qemu):

[image]

Now this is what it looks like on real hardware:
[image]

Can someone please let me know what is going on here and what I could do to solve the issue.

Here is the `printf` code:

```
printf:
  pusha
  mov ah, 0x0e    ; Teletype output function
  str_loop:
    mov al, [si]  ; Load a character byte to al
    cmp al, 0
    jne print_char  ; if al != 0, jmp to print_char
    popa
    ret

  print_char:
    int 0x10    ; 0x10 interrupt
    inc si    ; add 1 to si
    jmp str_loop
```

printh:

```
printh:
push cx
push di
push bx

mov si, HEX_PATTERN   ; Load HEX_PATTERN memory location to si
mov cl, 12
mov di, 0

.hexLoop:
  mov bx, dx      ; copy dx to bx to preserve original hex value
  shr bx, cl      ; Shift value in bx 12 bits (3 bytes) right
  and bx, 0x000F  ; mask first 3 digits
  mov bx, [bx + HEX_TABLE]  ; load ascii character from HEX_TABLE into bx
  mov [HEX_PATTERN + di], bl  ; insert byte bl into correct spot in HEX_PATTERN
  sub cl, 4       ; change bits shifted in next iteration
  inc di          ; add 1 to insertion location in HEX_PATTERN

  cmp di, 4       ; since HEX_PATTERN.length = 4:
  je .exit        ; if (di == 4) {exit the loop}

jmp .hexLoop

.exit:
call printf     ; print HEX_PETTERN which is now populated

pop bx
pop di
pop cx
ret

HEX_PATTERN db '****h', 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
HEX_TABLE db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

read_disk:

```
;in=============================
;AL - sectors to read count
;CL - sector to read into memory
;DI - location to load
;out===========================
;CF - error

read_disk:
  pusha
  mov ah, 02h            ;We want to read a device
  mov dl, 80h            ;Spcificly a hard disk. Note: Floppy/SSDs are 00h
  mov ch, 0              ;Start at clyender 1
  mov dh, 0              ;Start at head 1
                         ;Address access pointer is where the memory is stored
                         ;This is at es:bx
  push bx
  mov bx, 0              ;Set bx to zero
  mov es, bx             ;Set segment to zero
  pop bx
  mov bx, di   ;Set offset to the address after our bootloader

  int 13h                ;Read from disk

  popa
  ret
```

And finally the main code:

```
org 0x7c00            ; add to offsets
bits 16

section .text
  global main



main:
cli          ;Disable interupts
jmp 0x0000:FIRST_STEP ;Make sure we load the correct address
%include "includes/first_step.s"

mov si, BOOTLOADER_STARTED
call printf

push ax
xor ax, ax
mov dl, 80h
int 13h

mov si, DISK_RESET_MSG
call printf

call testA20
mov dx, ax
call printh

call enableA20

call testA20
mov dx, ax
call printh



mov al, 1
mov cl, 2
mov di, [SECTOR_TWO_MEMORY_LOCATION]
call read_disk
jc disk_read_error

jmp [SECTOR_TWO_MEMORY_LOCATION]

hlt

disk_read_error:
  mov si, DISK_ERROR_MSG
  call printf
  hlt

%include "includes/bootlibrary.s"


SECTOR_TWO_MEMORY_LOCATION dw 0x7C00 + 512
BOOTLOADER_STARTED db "DKBootLoader has started", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
DISK_RESET_MSG db "Reset disk", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
DISK_ERROR_MSG db "Error reading disk. DKOS cannot boot", 0


times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; make sure file is 510 bytes in size
dw 0xaa55             ; write boot signiture



mov si, DISK_SUCSESSFULLY_READ
call printf

mov si, CHECKING_LONG_MODE
call printf

call check_long_mode
push ax
test ax, 0
pop dx
call printh
je long_mode_enabled

long_mode_disabled:
  mov si, LONG_MODE_DISABLED_MSG
  call printf
  hlt

long_mode_enabled:
mov si, LONG_MODE_ENABLED_MSG
call printf
hlt

%include "check_long_mode.s"

DISK_SUCSESSFULLY_READ db "Disk sucsessfully read. In second sector", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
CHECKING_LONG_MODE db "Checking long mode", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0

LONG_MODE_ENABLED_MSG db "Long mode is enabled", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
LONG_MODE_DISABLED_MSG db "Long mode is not avaliable", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0

times (512*2)-($-$$) db 0 ; make sure file is 510 bytes in size
```

If there are any more functions that you need, let me know. This is where I think it may be failing.

Finally, here is a hex dump:

```
00000000: faea 067c 0000 31c0 8ed0 8ed8 8ec0 8ee0  ...|..1.........
00000010: 8ee8 bc00 7cfc be7f 7de8 3900 5031 c0b2  ....|...}.9.P1..
00000020: 80cd 13be 9a7d e82c 00e8 9300 89c2 e834  .....}.,.......4
00000030: 00e8 c200 e888 0089 c2e8 2900 b001 b102  ..........).....
00000040: 8b3e 7d7d e862 0072 05ff 267d 7df4 bea7  .>}}.b.r..&}}...
00000050: 7de8 0100 f460 b40e 8a04 3c00 7502 61c3  }....`....<.u.a.
00000060: cd10 46eb f351 5753 be91 7cb1 0cbf 0000  ..F..QWS..|.....
00000070: 89d3 d3eb 83e3 0f8b 9f99 7c88 9d91 7c80  ..........|...|.
00000080: e904 4783 ff04 7402 ebe6 e8c8 ff5b 5f59  ..G...t......[_Y
00000090: c32a 2a2a 2a68 0a0d 0030 3132 3334 3536  .****h...0123456
000000a0: 3738 3941 4243 4445 4660 b402 b280 b500  789ABCDEF`......
000000b0: b600 53bb 0000 8ec3 5b89 fbcd 1361 c360  ..S.....[....a.`
000000c0: a1fe 7d53 bbff ff8e c35b bb0e 7e26 8b17  ..}S.....[..~&..
000000d0: 39d0 7405 61b8 0100 c3a1 ff7d 53bb ffff  9.t.a......}S...
000000e0: 8ec3 5bbb 0f7e 268b 1739 d074 0561 b801  ..[..~&..9.t.a..
000000f0: 00c3 6131 c0c3 60b8 0124 cd15 e8c0 ff83  ..a1..`..$......
00000100: f801 744c fbe8 5000 b0ad e664 e849 00b0  ..tL..P....d.I..
00000110: d0e6 64e8 4900 e460 50e8 3c00 b0d1 e664  ..d.I..`P.<....d
00000120: e835 0058 0c02 e660 e82d 00b0 aee6 64e8  .5.X...`.-....d.
00000130: 2600 fbe8 89ff 83f8 0174 15e4 920c 02e6  &........t......
00000140: 92e8 7bff 3c01 7408 be66 7de8 07ff ebfe  ..{.<.t..f}.....
00000150: be6f 7de8 fffe 61c3 e464 a802 75fa c3e4  .o}...a..d..u...
00000160: 64a8 0174 fac3 4e6f 2041 3230 0a0d 0041  d..t..No A20...A
00000170: 3230 2045 6e61 626c 6564 0a0d 0000 7e44  20 Enabled....~D
00000180: 4b42 6f6f 744c 6f61 6465 7220 6861 7320  KBootLoader has 
00000190: 7374 6172 7465 640a 0d00 5265 7365 7420  started...Reset 
000001a0: 6469 736b 0a0d 0045 7272 6f72 2072 6561  disk...Error rea
000001b0: 6469 6e67 2064 6973 6b2e 2044 4b4f 5320  ding disk. DKOS 
000001c0: 6361 6e6e 6f74 2062 6f6f 7400 0000 0000  cannot boot.....
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa  ..............U.
00000200: be6c 7ee8 4ffe be97 7ee8 49fe e818 0050  .l~.O...~.I....P
00000210: a900 005a e84e fe74 07be c37e e836 fef4  ...Z.N.t...~.6..
00000220: beac 7ee8 2ffe f460 669c 6658 6689 c166  ..~./..`f.fXf..f
00000230: 3500 0020 0066 5066 9d66 9c66 5866 31c8  5.. .fPf.f.fXf1.
00000240: 7425 66b8 0000 0080 0fa2 663d 0100 0080  t%f.......f=....
00000250: 7215 66b8 0100 0080 0fa2 66f7 c200 0000  r.f.......f.....
00000260: 2074 0461 31c0 c361 b801 00c3 4469 736b   t.a1..a....Disk
00000270: 2073 7563 7365 7373 6675 6c6c 7920 7265   sucsessfully re
00000280: 6164 2e20 496e 2073 6563 6f6e 6420 7365  ad. In second se
00000290: 6374 6f72 0a0d 0043 6865 636b 696e 6720  ctor...Checking 
000002a0: 6c6f 6e67 206d 6f64 650a 0d00 4c6f 6e67  long mode...Long
000002b0: 206d 6f64 6520 6973 2065 6e61 626c 6564   mode is enabled
000002c0: 0a0d 004c 6f6e 6720 6d6f 6465 2069 7320  ...Long mode is 
000002d0: 6e6f 7420 6176 616c 6961 626c 650a 0d00  not avaliable...
000002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000330: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000340: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000350: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000370: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

What is the reason for this and what can I do to fix it? I have also tried reading different disks too.
That does not work either.

As well as the strings not showing correctly, the second sector does not seem to load either.

I also ran qemu with the file `/dev/disk2` which is my hard drive. No issues there. Only on a physical computer.

**Edit**:

As requested, here is first_steps.s:

```
FIRST_STEP:
             ;Zero out all general purpose registers
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov sp, main ;Set our stack pointer to the address of our 'main'lable
cld          ;Clear the direction flag - controls order we read strings
```

Comment: First off you should not be hard coding the boot drive number. The BIOS passes the drive being booted from in _DL_ when control is passed to your bootloader by the BIOS. You can use that in your disk reads and writes. I assume you are booting as a hard drive on your real hardware?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the tip there. Yes, I am booting from my hard drive from a physical computer. I also tried booting from other disk numbers and my boot loader displayed an error saying it could not read from the disk. As I expected.

Comment: What happens if you do not disable interrupts and ensure they are on. (Change CLI to STI)

Comment: You don't show us `includes/first_step.s` so I really hope you are setting up SS:SP (like maybe set it to 0x0000:0x7c00) so that you don't read sectors unexpectedly on top of the stack the BIOS may have used which could cause bad things to happen when a disk read is in progress.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've attached the requested code in the edit. I tested using `sti` in qemu and it works exactly the same. I'm going to have to wait until I get back to my uni next week to test it on a physical machine as I am using a Mac with UEFI boot and not BIOS boot.

Comment: I'm going to guess that is a dump of the binary file the assembler generated which might not be the same as the image on disk. What method did you use to write binary to fixed media?

Comment: @Shift_Left I used the `dd` command to write it to my hard drive. This means the hex dump you see is exactly the same as the first 1024 bytes on my hard drive.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, I would simplify the code by only implementing necessary functionality. Not that using ORG is wrong, but this preamble guarantees it will work with even some of the quirky BIOS out there. I think it's safe to assume your not using a linker, so sections are of no benefit in a flat binary file.

**Preamble**

```
    BOOT_SEG    equ 0x7c00
         TTY    equ 0x0E
       VIDEO    equ 0x10

    jmp     BOOT_SEG:Start      ; Guarantee that CS = 0x7c00:Start

Start:  
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax          ; Initialize primary segment registers

    ; Then set stack pointer to a safe place (*98000H*) but this does make the
    ; assumption that machine has at least 1M of ram.

    cli
    mov ax, 0x9000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x8000
    sti
```

Displaying null terminated strings can be optimized too. BIOS does not alter anything that doesn't need to be and this way SI points to the next string in memory if there is one.

```
printf:
    mov ah, TTY
 .L0:
    lodsb
    or  al, al
    jnz .J1
    ret
  .J1:
    int VIDEO
    jmp .L0
```

Emulators are marvelous tools, but on my test machine I use an actual version of DOS 6.2 which is monumentally handy in diagonsing some problems. In any event, I think if you implement Preamble, I'm fairly confident that it will solve your issue or if nothing else, exclude from the possibilites.

Comment: Thanks for that. Shall try next week can you explain to me why `org 0x7C00` is wrong when it is in so many tutorials? Also why do we change the stack pointer location instead of keeping it where it is? Also is this moving the stack pointer to `0x9000:0x8000` which is 0x98000?

Comment: Using ORG is not wrong, it's just if you ever encountered a BIOS that passes CS as 0x7c00 then code that wasn't ORG 0 wouldn't work. I've adopted this method mostly because when I do a source code listing, something at 0x1CD is also at 0x1CD in a hex dump and on disk.

Comment: Most often the stack is safe where it is, but moving it way up in memory guarantees there will never be a conflict as some BIOS stuff the stack just above real mode IVT at 50:1000. Setting CS:IP & SS:SP are just simply a means by which to assure those are not the source of a problem.

Comment: Yes, that is analogous too 9000:8000 or 9800:0000 or 9100:7000 etc etc.

Comment: @Shift_Left : The OPs code contains this line `jmp 0x0000:FIRST_STEP` .This actually sets _CS_ to 0 (it is a FAR JMP that sets both segment AND offset). He then sets all the other segment registers to 0. It doesn't  matter what segment:offset the BIOS used to transfer control to his code. He sets them all to 0 and ORG 0x7c00 so there is nothing wrong with his code in that regard at all

Comment: And the BIOS will not use _CS_ as 0x7c00. That would put the physical address starting at 0x7c000. I think you meant 0x07c0  which would put the start of the segment at physical address 0x7c00

Comment: Since you didn't use an ORG it defaulted to 0x0000. That means this is wrong `BOOT_SEG    equ 0x7c00` It should be `BOOT_SEG    equ 0x07c0`

Comment: If you are going to use any of the string instructions like LODSB you should be making sure you set the direction bit properly. In this case you want it forward with the code you have so you will need to use CLD to clear it (clear=forward / set=backward). You can't assume that the direction flag will be clear by the BIOS.

Comment: As for why you set SS:SP, one reason is that when you are reading from disk to memory you don't want to read disk sectors on top of the stack area that the BIOS has set up. Such corruption will almost certainly make the disk interrupts fail. Setting SS:SP somewhere that you know you aren't going to read on top of is a very good thing.

Comment: Just tried doing this in QEMU. When removing org and adding the jump and start code as you said, my program does not start at all.

Comment: Also just 'starting it from scratch', and the code you gave on its own crashes QEMU.

Comment: Technically I've given you two snippets not programs, so yes it will crash if you just assembly as is.